# Find a power series representation for the function. (Assume $a > 0$.)

Tags: calculus, functions, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm down to my last attempt (my teacher allows $5$ tries per question)! Thank you!!

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\frac{x^7}{a^8-x^8}=\frac{x^7}{a^8}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{x}{a})^8}=\frac{x^7}{a^8}\sum_{i=0}^\infty(\frac{x}{a})^{8i}$ with convergence interval as $|\frac{x}{a}|<1$